# Boost converter voltage drop when connected to load

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, buck-boost

I have designed a boost converter based around the TPS61200 chip. This is a low voltage boost converter with a varying input of around 1.5V and 400mA.

The output of the circuit is 3.3V. However, when I connect a load (3.3V fan that draws 60mA) the voltage drops to 1.5V output. When I connected a motor (3V that draws 18mA) the voltage dropped to 50mV output!

I've also purchased an off the shelf module which experiences the same issue, so it's probably not my circuit design.

The components I'm using on the board are the following:

- Boost IC - TPS61200 (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61200.pdf?ts=1598365314165&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DTPS61200DRCR)
- 1MOhm resistor - RCC04021M00FKED (https://www.vishay.com/docs/20066/rcce3.pdf)
- 180kOhm resistor - RTT03184JTP (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811081933_RALEC-RTT03184JTP_C103362.pdf)
- 2.2uH inductor - CKCS5040-2.2uH/M-2131 (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_CENKER-CKCS5040-2-2uH-M-2131_C354604.pdf)
- 10uF capacitor - RDEC71H106K3K1H03B (https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/281/RDE_X7R_X7S_25V-100V_E-1671041.pdf)
- 1uF capacitor - RDER72A105K2M1H03A (https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/281/c49e-506.pdf)

The off-the-shelf board is from SparkFun: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10255
I shorted the UVLO as I didn't need it, and set it to 3.3V. I've also tried it on 5V and had the same issue.

The schematic for the circuit I designed:
[image: My circuit design]

The schematic for the off-the-shelf module:
[image: Sparkfun module schematic]

Thanks all for your help in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: Show the schematic and link data sheets to parts used.

Comment: Cheers for the advice. Added in schematics and datasheet links.

Comment: What voltage do you measure at the *input* under these conditions?  What powers the input?  What exact procedure was used to measure the current draw of the loads?

Comment: The input is around 1.5V 300mAh. A Peliter module is the source of power. The current draw is measured using a multi-meter in series with the load

Comment: And you measured that input voltage *while the load was connected and the output was droopping?*

Comment: The input voltage was measured immediately before the load was connected. I've just measured during load. The input voltage dropped to around 550mV during loading.

Comment: Test the converters running from a fresh Duracell. If they work, the Peltier is the problem not the converters. Getting 3.3V 60mA (0.2W) from a Peltier is beyond optimistic.

Comment: I've just done some more measurements when connecting the motor. The input voltage drops from 1.5A to 1.3A which is a lot less. The output drops from 3.3V to 0.5V. I'll try with the AA battery. As a side note, without load the peliter module is giving off 1.5V and 400mA when shorted. Doesn't this mean that it supplys a power of 600mW?

Comment: Did you measure current and voltage at the same time?  1.5V at 400mA would be 600mW, but only if they are simultaneous.  If you measure 1.5V open circuit, then measure 400mA short circuit current, the odds are very good that the voltage is **not** 1.5V while you are measuring the current.

Comment: I did not measure them at the same time. I only have one multi-meter unfortunately.

Comment: I tried using a Duracell 1.5V battery on the boost converter. I had a similar issue, but with a power drop from 1450mV to 1250mV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've just measured during load. The input voltage dropped to around 550mV during loading.

This indicates that your power source is simply not capable of supplying this load.

A boost converter cannot *create* power, it can only wastefully transform one voltage*current option to another having *lesser* total power.

Comment: It seems like I wasn't measuring voltage and current supply simultaneously from the power input. Once I've done tso and verified that this is the issue I'll mark as solved :)

Comment: Yep this was the case, under load the measured power of the polite module is far less than what it was when using the open circuit voltage.